# Stub `rand` with multiple future values

Tags: ruby, random, testunit

**I know:**

```
require 'mocha/setup'

Kernel.stub(:rand, -1) do
  p Kernel.rand #=> -1
  p Kernel.rand #=> -1
  p Kernel.rand #=> -1
end
```

**I need:**

```
Kernel.stub(:rand, [-1, -2, -3]) do
  p Kernel.rand #=> -1
  p Kernel.rand #=> -2
  p Kernel.rand #=> -3
end
```

How can I program multiple future values for `random` in my test?

Answer (score 0):

```
Kernel.stubs(:rand).returns(-1, -2, -3)
```

http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Expectation.html#returns-instance_method

Comment: don't works : NoMethodError: undefined method `stubs' for Kernel:Module, need a gem?

Comment: That means that mocha is no loaded. Load it through tests or "require 'mocha/setup'"

Comment: "NoMethodError: undefined method `__metaclass__' for Kernel:Module" when adding this require...

Comment: the test run yes : "1) Error:
CharacterTest#test_test:
NoMethodError: undefined method `__metaclass__' for Kernel:Module"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sample` method to return a random value from an array.

```
[-1,-2,-3].sample #=> -1
[-1,-2,-3].sample #=> -3
[-1,-2,-3].sample #=> -2
[-1,-2,-3].sample #=> -1
[-1,-2,-3].sample #=> -1
```

So you can do

```
Kernel.stubs(:rand).returns([-1,-2,-3].sample)
```

Comment: Kernel.stubs(:rand).returns(...) don't works, look the com. on windock answer.